# UITableView deleterows scroll to top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a query to delete specified rows in UITableView but the problem when the deleteRows is called the UITableView scroll to top so how to prevent it scrolling to top? and why it scroll to top!

I try called a method to force it scroll to down but the tableview scroll to top first after return
the code of remove

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(self.roomId).observe(.childRemoved, with: {(snap) in
        print("child Removed")
        for msg in self.messageArray {
            let message: NSDictionary = msg as! NSDictionary
            let messageContent: [String: Any] = message as! [String: Any]
            if messageContent["messageID"] as! String == snap.key {
                let indexRemoved = self.messageArray.index(of: msg)
                self.messageArray.remove(msg)
                self.userArray.removeObject(at: indexRemoved)
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexRemoved, section: 0)
                print(indexPath)
                self.conversationTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
                break;
            }   
        }
        })
```

Comment: may be it's not exactly things you wants, but you should not doing delete row in every loop scope. create array on first line in closure, and just adds indexpath of deletes. after end of loop, delete with array that added.

Comment: what's the difference? besides my problem is the change of scroll not the delete itself

Comment: I did not find any scroll related issues in the source. I suspect there is any logic to update the entire table at cellForRowAt indexPath or elsewhere to set the cell. Having the whole code means that others can figure out the exact cause.
And right. That is not the cause, but it is not good code for UITableView to run deleteRows one by one in the loop.

Comment: deleteRows function can receive array.

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure you are not using table view method like 'estimatedHeightFor...' to calculate hight to scroll table view after row delete. One more point to be sure is, reloadData method should not use when deleting row from table view if you don't want to table scrolling.

If all are good then on deleting a particular row, table view will move all rows up to fill deleted row empty space.

Comment: I use both estimatedHeightForRowAt and heightForRowAt to make cell auto-resizing, if there is a problem when deleting so how to prevent tableview call them after delete ?
and the other point of the reloadData I didn't call it after delete

Comment: Its ok to use heightForRowAt but estimatedHeightForRowAt makes table view auto scroll to top. Actually,  why its happens i don't know but for now, i could say only, plz try without estimatedHeightForRowAt and then plz let me know what is the output ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code that can be easily corrected.

First before doing anything, grab the current scroll position of the first visible item (given the cells are the same size)

```
let savedIndex = myTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first
```

then once the row is deleted from the array and you reload the tableview, you can return to where it was with

```
myTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(savedIndex, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
```

If you need another option (variable heights), you can use

```
tableView.contentOffset.y;
```

Also, there's no need to iterate over the entire array to find the row to delete from it. Assuming the Firebase nodes(s) data are stored in the array as a class, in the array with the Firebase key as a property of each class, you can simply get the index of that element in the array and remove it. Here's an option

```
let key = snapshot.key

if let index = self.myArray.indexOf({$0.firebaseKey == key}) {
     self.myArray.removeAtIndex(index)
     self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

This object would look like:

```
class MyClass {
    var firebaseKey: String?
    var some_var: String?
    var another_var: String?
}
```