# tableview scrolls when adding/deleting data in swift 2.3

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase

Re-wording this question as I understand the problem better:
I have a UITableview and I am reloading data from Firebase when theres any activity. I use

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 330
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

So anytime my tableview source gets updated - a new post gets added or deleted, my UI tableview will scroll one cell up or down to accomodate for this new activity. How do I make sure my cell stays in the same position when tableview gets updated ?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 1000
}
```

Comment: Your app probably adds observers to a node in Firebase and when there's an event (add, edit or remove) in that node, the app responds to it. Most likely a tableView is refreshed during one of those observe events. However, there's no way to tell since there's no code in your question. See [Asking Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes, I do download data and update my tableview using 
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

Comment: You don't need dispatch_async and without code in your question it's hard to advise further.

Comment: Ah. see my answer to this is question [Scroll To Top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502325/uitableview-deleterows-scroll-to-top/41512290#41512290) as it should provide you direction

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't really work for me. Infact this line ends p crashing the app on load as it is nil:

myTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(savedIndex, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)

Comment: You may have overlooked some of the points in the provided link. Before reloading the tableView *when there's an event*, capture the current scroll position, reload and populate your array datasource then return to the scroll position, or the closest point to it. If you try to scroll to a nonexistent (nil) position when the app loads, it would obviously crash.